# If $A$ is a complex full row rank matrix, why is $A A^T$ necessarily invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are standard proofs of $ A A^* $ being invertible, but what about $ A A^T $? I am asking this because I want to understand a theorem from wikipedia that states that for a full row rank matrix $A$ it holds that $ A^T (A A^T)^{-1} $ is a right inverse.

Comment: one way to prove is by using [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

Comment: Try $A=(1, \mathrm{i})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true for complex matrices. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}i & 1\end{pmatrix}$ as a counterexample.